# Delete node from Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on iterative delete function that deletes node from a linked list, I think that the code is supposed to work fine. But when I can't use "delete" to delete the first Node of the List.
The code is:
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* GetNewNode(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node* Insert(Node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = GetNewNode(data);

    }
    else
        root->next = Insert(root->next, data);
    return root;
}

void Delete_k(Node *root, int k)
{

    int i = 0;
    Node* P = new Node;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        P = root;
        root = root->next;
        delete P;

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k - 2; i++)
        {
            root = root->next;
        }
        root->next = root->next->next;
    }
}

void Output(Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = root->next;
    }
    while (root != NULL)
    {
        cout << root->data << " ";
        root = root->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, a, pos;
    Node* root = NULL;
    cout << "Input your list hear: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        root = Insert(root, n);
        cin >> n;
    }
    Output(root);
    cout << "\nDelete Pos?: ";
    cin >> pos;
    Delete_k(root, pos);
    Output(root);
}
```

I have problem in this

```
void Delete_k(Node *root, int k)
{

    int i = 0;
    Node* P = new Node;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        P = root;
        root = root->next;
        delete P;

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k - 2; i++)
        {
            root = root->next;
        }
        root->next = root->next->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the test code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @JamesWierzba yes, this code doesn't work if you choose 1 to delete.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statements are giving you issues?

Comment: You must have some test case code, that you ran, and didn't like the results. It would help us to see that code.

Comment: Have you tried printing / displaying variables using `std::cout`?

Comment: @JamesWierzba 
I input 1 2 3 4 5 6 for the test case. When I chose k=1 to delete, the program seem to be run in the infinite loop.

Comment: In output: `if (root == NULL) root = root->next;` if there is no root, get the next item after the non-existent root. Almost certainly not what you want to do.

Comment: `Delete_K` leaks memory.

Answer (score 3):

The problem:

```
void Delete_k(Node *root, int k)
```

The value at root is pass by reference, but the pointer to it is not.

Result: `Delete_k`'s root is a copy of `main`'s root. Delete_K's root gets repointed and deleted. Main's root now points at garbage memory. End game program.

Solution:

Provide a reference to the root pointer so that it doesn't get copied.

```
void Delete_k(Node *& root, int k)
```

Or return root from Delete_k.

```
Node * Delete_k(Node * root, int k)
{
    //existing code
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a perfect solution. My problem is solved.